# Dplyr Error: Error in UseMethod("src_tbls")

Tags: r, dplyr, rodbc

I am trying to connect to SQL db using RODBC and DPLYR as shown below:

```
library(RODBC)
library(dplyr)

print("Attempting Connection")

data_odbc <- odbcDriverConnect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};
                                 SERVER=localServer12;
                               DATABASE=testDB;
                               UID=user1;
                               PWD=pwd;
                               Trusted_Connection=yes')

print("Connection Established")

src_tbls(data_odbc)

close(data_odbc)


print("Connection Closed")
```

However when I run this R Script I get the Error below:

```
Error in UseMethod("src_tbls") : 
  no applicable method for 'src_tbls' applied to an object of class "RODBC"
```

How can I resolve this?

-Thanks.

Comment: dplyr is essentially a front end for particular types of operations on particular types of data. It needs a backend to be able to perform the operations. The error is telling you it doesn't know how to work with ODBC connections. For SQL Server you can try https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer

Comment: I will try this. Thanks